# how to fix maximum number of major ticks in kendo charts

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-treeview, kendo-scheduler

Need to adjust maximum number of major ticks in kendo charts.and we have a possibility of

```
 .MajorTicks(m => m.Visible(true).step())
 .MajorTicks(m => m.Visible(true).skip())
```

similarly is there any possibility to fix maximum number of major ticks in all kendo charts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a problem when kendo charts are loading in side by side all labels are collapsed with each other .

I used steps for labels so it got appearing labels clearly.